# Truncate every member of a slice using Go

Tags: string, go

I just started with Go, and I'm having a little trouble accomplishing what I want to do. After loading a large text file in which each line begins with a word I want in my array, followed by single and multi-space delimited text I do not care about.

My first line of code creates an array of lines

```
lines := strings.Split( string( file ), "\n" )
```

The next step would be to truncate each line  which I can do with a split statement.  I'm sure I could do this with a for loop but I'm trying to learn some of the more efficient operations in Go (compared to c/c++)

I was hoping I could do something like this

```
lines := strings.Split( (lines...), "  " )
```

Is there a better way to do this or should I just use some type of for loop?

Comment: You can take a look at bufio package. https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines

Answer (score 2):

Using `bufio.NewScanner` then `word := strings.Fields(scanner.Text())` and `slice = append(slice, word[0])` like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := ` wanted1 not wanted 
    wanted2 not wanted 

    wanted3 not wanted 

    `
    slice := []string{}
    // scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(s))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        word := strings.Fields(scanner.Text())
        if len(word) > 0 {
            slice = append(slice, word[0])
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

Using `strings.Fields(line)` like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s := `
    wanted1 not wanted 
    wanted2 not wanted 

    wanted3 not wanted 

    `

    lines := strings.Split(s, "\n")
    slice := make([]string, 0, len(lines))
    for _, line := range lines {
        words := strings.Fields(line)
        if len(words) > 0 {
            slice = append(slice, words[0])
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

output:

```
[wanted1 wanted2 wanted3]
```